# Person Class is repeating the same inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to create a class called "Person" simply just adding users by their first name, last name, age and country including an auto numbering ID. Although when I enter the details, the details all displaying the same details repeatedly where I want the ID to increment by 1 like user 1 belongs to ID 1, user 2 belongs to ID 2 etc.

**How I want my program to work:**

```
------------------------------
ID: 1
FIRST NAME: John
LAST NAME: Smith
AGE: 32
COUNTRY: United Kingdom
------------------------------
------------------------------
ID: 2 
FIRST NAME: Amanda
LAST NAME: Smith
AGE: 56
COUNTRY: Germany
------------------------------
```

**How my Program is displaying:**

```
Enter First Name: John
Enter Last Name: Smith
Enter Age: 32
Enter Country: United Kindom
Add another person? Y or N: N
Finished
------------------------------
ID: 1
FIRST NAME: John
LAST NAME: Smith
AGE: 32
COUNTRY: United Kingdom
------------------------------
------------------------------
ID: 1
FIRST NAME: John
LAST NAME: Smith
AGE: 32
COUNTRY: United Kingdom
------------------------------
```

Could anyone point me to where I'm going wrong here? or How I could resolve my problem?

**My Python Code:**

```
class Person:
    personid = 0

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age, country):
        self.personid =+ 1
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.country = country

    def addPerson(self):
        person = []
        person.append(self.personid)
        person.append(self.firstname)
        person.append(self.lastname)
        person.append(self.age)
        person.append(self.country)

    def displayPeople(self):
        print("-" * 30)
        print("PERSON ID: ",self.personid)
        print('FIRST NAME:',self.firstname,'\nLAST 
        NAME:',self.lastname,'\nAGE:',self.age,'\nCOUNTRY:',self.country)
        print("-" * 30)

    def addAnotherPerson(self):
        option = input("Add another person? Y or N: ")
        if option == "Y":
            Person(
                firstname=input("Enter First Name: "),
                lastname=input("Enter Last Name: "),
                age=input("Enter Age: "),
                country=input("Enter Country: ")
            )
            Person.addAnotherPerson(self)
            Person.displayPeople(self)
        else:
            print("Finished")
            Person.displayPeople(self)

 perx = Person(
    firstname = input("Enter First Name: "),
    lastname = input("Enter Last Name: "),
    age = input("Enter Age: "),
    country = input("Enter Country: ")
 )
 perx.addPerson()
 perx.displayPeople()
 perx.addAnotherPerson()
```

Comment: What is the point of `addPerson()`? It makes a list out of all the attributes, but doesn't save that list anywhere.

Comment: The `Person` class shouldn't be responsible for lists of people. It should just handle the data for a single person, use another class for collections.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above comments:

In order to promote the person_id, you want to explicitly update the **class** member and not the instance member.

This is what you need:

```
class Person:
    cls_personid = 0

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, age, country):
        type(self).cls_personid += 1

        self.personid = self.cls_personid
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.country = country


a = Person('a1','b1', 11, 'xyz')
b = Person('a2','b2', 12, 'xyz')
print(a.personid)  # -> 1
print(b.personid)  # -> 2
```